# Making an absolutely-positioned centered image responsive

Tags: css

I'm currently aligning an image to the bottom of my div as well as centering it with the following css:

html:

```
<div class="hello">
  <img src="http://bit.ly/1gHcL8T" class="helloImage" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.hello {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative; 
}

.helloImage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

However, I want to make this image also responsive by giving it a width as percentage. How would I accomplish this?

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8e7UM/1/

Comment: First things first. You would need to post your HTML or create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're supporting modern browsers, you can do [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/8e7UM/3/).

```
.helloImage {
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

And [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8e7UM/4/) is the basic version, without the fancy transforms.

```
.helloImage {
    left: 10%;
    right: 20%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```